# Why date format become strange after + MonthEnd(1)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to convert a pandas column with year and month to monthend by using below statement

df['Month'] = df['Month'] + MonthEnd(1)

```
Month
202108
202107
202106
```

My ideal output is

```
Month
2021-08-31
2021-07-31
2021-06-30
```

But the output becomes

```
Month
1970-01-31 00:00:000202108
1970-01-31 00:00:000202107
1970-01-31 00:00:000202106
```

How can I convert the column back to the previous format? Or how can I get the monthend correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the "Month" column to datetime and then add `MonthEnd(1)`:

```py
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

df["Month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Month"], format="%Y%m") + MonthEnd(0)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       Month
0 2021-08-31
1 2021-07-31
2 2021-06-30
```

---

EDIT: Changed to `+ MonthEnd(0)`

Comment: You might want `+ MonthEnd(0)` because `pd.to_datetime('2021-08-31') + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1) => Timestamp('2021-09-30 00:00:00')` which is likely not the expected.